# How to return Response with custom status code and message as JSON for response body with Slim Framework

Tags: php, json, slim

I'm new with Slim framework. I want to know how to return response with the body and status code as I wish. For now, it only performs as I wish if the query returns records, but not if the query failed (e.g. select * from notexiststable) or returns nothing and with Firefox I see the status is 204 in both cases.

So here's the code:

```
$app->get('/models', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $conn = getConnection();
    $result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM model where m_id = 2;");  //this will return 0 record!

    if  (!$result) {
        $data = array("Error Message" => 'Query did not execute successfully');
        $newResponse = $response->withJson($data, 500);
    }
    else {
        if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            $data = array("Warning Message" => "There's no existent Model!");
            $newResponse = $response->withJson($data, 204);

        }
        else {
            $data = array();
            while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $data['Models'][] = $row;               
            }
            $newResponse = $response->withJson($data, 200);
        }
    }

    return $newResponse;

});
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: can you show `var_dump($result);` output

Comment: Hi, I've put it and got wamp64\www\project\RESTapi\index.php:20:resource(65, pgsql result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status code `204` is `No Content` and the HTTP specification notes that there cannot be a body in the message.

Change the status code for your error to an error code, such as `400`.

ie. Change:

```
if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    $data = array("Warning Message" => "There's no existent Model!");
    $newResponse = $response->withJson($data, 204);
}
```

to:

```
if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    $data = array("Warning Message" => "There's no existent Model!");
    $newResponse = $response->withJson($data, 400);
}
```

and the JSON will be sent to the client.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Would you mind telling me how to prevent user seeing the following in case that the query failed? **<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near &amp;quot;=&amp;quot;
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM quality_model wherm_id = 2;**

Comment: Turn off display_errors in your PHP.ini on your live site.